# Jekyll and GitHub layout issues

Tags: github, jekyll, github-pages

I've had my blog on github for a Jekyll. Out of nowhere, when I drill into a post, the formatting of the post is not right.

Any suggestions on what to tweak to get it back to it's defaults?

https://dfinke.github.io/
https://github.com/dfinke/dfinke.github.io

Comment: The post layout isn't being used. However, your posts seem to call it fine, and I can't see anything in `_config` that would affect this. That makes me think this is a build issue. Are you building locally and pushing up? If so, perhaps a deprecated dependency issue?

Comment: Thanks for the clues @TBB . I'm not building locally. I search for github pages issues next.

Comment: @tbb I reinstalled ruby, did a round of updates. When I did the `bundle exec jekyll serve` it told me the `gems` keyword was deprecated. I fixed it, checked it in. The blog looks correct locally. The GitHub pages still do not render correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS is not loading.

AND your `main.js` isn't loading either, and it is being called twice, and it is being called from the posts directoy like the css above.

The problem appears to be paths.

For example, your path to the css is currently the individual post's path:

`https://dfinke.github.io/2017/Microsoft-PowerShell-Yaml-and-VSTS/css/main.css`

Whereas I think you want it from root (looking at your files):

`https://dfinke.github.io/css/main.css`

Your `head.html` include states this:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ "css/main.css" | prepend: site.baseurl }}">`

I note your `_config` sets site url as 'https://dfinke.github.io' and baseurl as '/'.

So that seems right to me from Jekyll perspective.

Something appears to be **changing** the url parts on your assets' paths.

I note you seem to have `.ps1` powershell scripts.

I don't know powershell scripting, but looking through `New-BlogPost.ps1` it does seem to be dealing with paths.

Perhaps github now runs powershell scripts, and that is now changing your paths somehow?

Hope that helps.

PS - If it is an issue caused by your powershell scripting, you may want to update the question title to reflect that for future readers.